# ShowDialog not opening form Visual Studio

Tags: c#

when i try to open a form on visual studio, it doesn't work. i've tried many solutions but it still doesn't work, could the problem be in a different code? here is the code that i am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VBR_Application
{
    public partial class addNewGT : Form
    {
        public addNewGT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addOnline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newForm = new AddOnline();
            newForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on `var newForm = new AddOnline();`. Run the code. click the button. Does the breakpoint get hit?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
private void addOnline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newForm = new Form();
    newForm.Show();

}
```

Comment: Almost certainly not. `Form` is the base class for all forms, it's not a specific form

Comment: I know, but did he mean that he just can't open a new form? Or `newForm.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want show a built in dialog you can use this one

```
 MessageBox.Show(this, "Title", "Message");
```

If you want a custom dialog you can also use this one

```
_FormDialog dialog = new _FormDialog(this);
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

_FormDialog is the widows form you have created.